# How to initialize a variable in global.asax and use it within other controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I implemented a variable in global.asax and I would like to use it within other controllers.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Be more specific please !!. Why do you want to declare it in Global.asax ?? You may add a `BaseController` and make all your controllers inherits from it.

Comment: do You want to pass the variable other controllers as a parameter?  show the variable which you are implemented .

Answer (score 1):

If your varialbe is static you can use this sintax - MvcApplication.VarName. Where MVCApplication your main class inherited from System.Web.HttpApplication, and VarName - your variable name.

Comment: Or you can use Application state to store your variable wich will be used by all users.